# BbPress Register Page in Breadcrumbs

Tags: plugins, bbpress, breadcrumb

For some reason, the Forums Register page in bbpress plugin is appearing in the breadcrumb, take a look: http://putonthestand.com/forums/topic/let-the-dead-bury-the-dead/